# difference between lack, shortage, weakness

Tags: synonyms

he becomes increasingly conscious of his ___ of fluency.

A shortage, B lack, C weakness.

The answer is lack. Can anyone explain what's the difference between these words?

Comment: Why did this get downvoted?

Comment: @MarkHubbard that's not exactly true, saying "Jane speaks *more fluently* than Bob" is perfectly good English.

Comment: Andy, I completely agree. And good answer, too. The question probably got down-voted (not by me) because proofreading and helping with homework are off-topic on EL&U.

Comment: @Andy: the tooltip that you see if you hover the mouse over the downvote button gives a short explanation of the usual reasons for downvoting: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." This question seems realatively clear, and it's a matter of opinion whether it is useful, but I think it pretty clearly lacks research effort. (I haven't downvoted because I'm out of votes for the day.) Someone who wants to know "what is the difference between these three specific words" should start by looking at their dictionary definitions.

Comment: @Andy: an example of a user who I think has a good format for asking questions like this is [cornejo](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/199659/cornejo). You see that  it's not necessary to include a ton of research, but it's nice to have links, or discussion of what the dictionary says, or just guesses about what the difference might be.

Comment: @sumelic hmmm.  So you're basically saying stack exchange's goal is to focus on hard questions rather than any valid questions?

Comment: @Andy: No, I'm saying a question is more likely to be downvoted if there is no apparent research effort

Comment: @sumelic but what exactly is the goal of such downvoting?  Simply to discourage asking questions without first trying to answer them for oneself?

Comment: I don't know why I got down vote either. This is not homework or something like that as I have already provided the answer, and I asked this question because I can't figure out the reason, I know the meaning of these three words. But there's no difference for me at that time. I did look up dictionary before I posted it here. If any one can tell me why it got down vote, I will try to ask more suitable next time. Anyway, Thank you for the answer and comments. It helps me a lot.

Comment: @Jacky Maybe because it *looks* like a question straight from an exam, people thought you were trying to cheat.  But you already provided the answer, so it's obvious you're only trying to understand why it's the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

"Shortage" usually refers to something *physical*, whereas "lack" often refers to something *immaterial*.

> Shortage of bread.
>   Shortage of teachers.
>   Shortage of apples.
>
> Lack of sanity.
>   Lack of fluency.
>   Lack of agreement.
>   Lack of understanding.

You can also refer to a "bread shortage", "teacher shortage", etc., but "sanity lack", "fluency lack", etc. are incorrect.

On the other hand, lack can also refer physical things:

> Lack of drinking water.
>   Lack of used cars.

"Shortage" often connotes that there is less of something than usual or intended -- for example, the shortage of oil in the US during the 1973 oil crisis.  Lack has no such connotation.

People will understand if you use either word in place of the other, but "shortage of sanity", "shortage of fluency", "shortage of agreement", etc. sound weird to a native speaker.

"Weakness of" is a very uncommon phrase in general.  Instead of referring to "the weakness of his muscles" I think it's more common to say "how weak his muscles are".